# Text Field is focusing on tap outside component

Tags: react-native, textfield

I have implemented a react-native-material-textfield `TextField` which is focusing on taps outside of the `TextField` component (but within a certain distance from the component). Why does this happen?

I have tried limiting the size of both `container` and `inputContainer`, as well as wrapping the TextField in a `View` shrinked to fit the `TextField` component.

This is my implementation of the `TextField`:

```js
<TextField
      ref={this.passwordRef}
      secureTextEntry={true}
      containerStyle={{width: 300, backgroundColor: 'green'}}
      inputContainerStyle={{width:300, backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}
      tintColor={'rgba(0, 0, 0, .38)'}
      fontSize={20}
      enablesReturnKeyAutomatically={true}
      autoCapitalize='none'
      autoCorrect={false}
      returnKeyType='done'
      label='Password'
      error={this.state.errors.password}
      onChangeText={this.handlePasswordChange}
      value={this.state.password}
      />
```

[image: Behavior of the TextField]

The expected behavior is that the `TextField` should focus when tapped, not when the target of a tap is outside the component.

Comment: What happens if you use flex: 0.7 ?

Comment: @Auticcat On what component? The container or the inputContainer?

Comment: Container, without width, just to check if the problem is width

Comment: The problem persists when containerStyle={{flex: 0.7, justifyContent: 'center'}}.

Comment: what is `TextField` component? Share with us the code

Comment: Would you please update your question with the screen component structure in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured this out. Even though no overflow was visible neither for the TextInput (referenced by `style`) nor the InputContainer (referenced by `inputContainerStyle`), setting the `overflow` prop to `hidden` for the `containerStyle` fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

set your style prop equal to the other widths:
style = {{width: 300}}

If you have a width it is also best to specify a height if your component is not wrapped in a View.